# Simple HTML question to warn staff they are in dev not prod

Tags: html

This script displays a static message on our development system, when you login to dev system. We have staff and programs who have still been working with paper. Some of them don't know not to enter live work in the development system, it's happened a few times. We train in dev so we wanted a warning script when you login to dev. I came up with this:

```
<br /><span style="color:red; font-size:36px;">Development System</span>
```

I'm looking to add more of a warning loop or any ideas to really grab their attention.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a (broad) UX question and not a programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanna catch attention you could also wrap that text into a div rather than a span, and make the background red.

Try this out:

```
<div class="dev-env-warning" >Development System</div>
```

```
.dev-env-warning {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

That will display a big red banner taking full width of the page.

**DEPRECATED, see edit**: If yo really want to make it seeable you can even wrap the "Devlopment System" into a blink tag like so :

```
<div class="dev-env-warning" ><blink>Development System</blink></div>
```

Not really beautiful but eye catchy for sure.

**EDIT**: the `<blink/>` tag is deprecated like Nakarukatoshi Uzumaki said in the comments. Here is a newer CSS solution that must be compatible with most browsers:

```
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
  from {opacity: 1.0;}
  to {opacity: 0.0;}
}
.blink{
    text-decoration: blink;
    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

So you can just paste this code in your css and add the .blink class to the span containing the text.

Comment: Just [don't use the <blink> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink).

Comment: Very true, just realized that was deprecated, i'll edit the answer